# Scala nested map filter

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I'm having a nested map which contains both map as well as a combination of List and None value like this

```scala
Map(
  test -> 113123, 
  "cat" -> None,
  crm -> List(age, gender, code), 
  myList -> Map(
    test2 -> 321323, 
    test3 -> 11122,
  )
)
```

But I wanted to filter out non-map values from an above-nested map

expected output:

```scala
Map(
  myList -> Map(
    test2 -> 321323,
    test3 -> 11122,
  )
)
```

Comment: Please note that I'm reading above value from JSON and parsing it using JSON parser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`collect` is your friend whenever you want to do something involving filtering a collection in a way that involves restricting to a certain type:

```
val map : Map[Any, Any] = Map(...)

map.collect {
  case (key, map: Map[_, _]) => (key, map)
}.toMap
```

Comment: I wanted output like this Map( myList -> Map(test2 -> 321323, test3 -> 11122)) but above code returning List (Key,map(key->value), please help me on this since im very new to scala

Comment: I mean it's returning List(myList , Map(test2 -> 321323, test3 -> 11122)) but i wanted Map(myList -> Map(test2 -> 321323, test3 -> 11122))

Comment: Ah, whoops - you need to explicitly call `.toMap` afterwards to get it back to a `Map` object. I've just edited my answer to add that.

Comment: I'm getting compile time exception for this val finalMappingValues= parsedJson.collect {
      case (key, map: Map[_, _]) => (key, map)
    }.toMap

Comment: I wanted to filter out based on key name like - List(age, gender, code) please any on help me on this